# How can I determine the average tone of a given area in a grayscale image using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have a grayscale image and I need to determine the average tone of its background. The problem is, that image has a few black spots, such that, if I tried to find the average tone of the whole image I would end up with a tone different than what I wanted. By manually zooming in to the background, I have found that the pixel tones oscillate between 180-195.

The approach I though of to solve this problem is by determining the average tone of a given area with no black spots in it (in the picture, the area enclosed by the black rectangle which I know the coordinates of). The problem is I have no idea how I would do that. Upon searching online I found a few articles that talked about determining the average color of a colored image, but nothing related to grayscale image, nor to average tone of a predetermined area.

I am using the OpenCV library for the rest of my image processing work and, if possible, would prefer to solve this problem using that library, but any help with this issue is greatly appreciated.

[image].

Comment: Just `result = im[y0:y1, x0:x1].mean()`

Comment: The average grayscale level in the area you've chosen is going to be much different from the average from the bottom-right of the image. What are you hoping to do with the average value that you obtain?

Comment: @beaker I need to threshold images with different background tones. Those images contain particles that need to be highlighted and brought to the foreground through thresholding. The different backgrounds require slight adjustments in the adaptive thresholding parameters. What I was hoping to do was figure out those adjustments by using using sample backgrounds with different tones. Then, I hoped to figure out a way to identify the background tone of a determined image with particles in it and have the algorithm use the thresholding parameters suitable for its background tone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain what you are actually trying to do here, but I think you want to determine the tone of the background and subtract that or do something based on that to identify where your particles are. Without investing too much effort in case I am completely wrong, here is an approach that you/we could adapt to OpenCV if you like it.

Divide the image into a 10x10 regular grid. Calculate the variance, or standard deviation within each of the resulting 100 rectangles. Choose the one with the lowest variance - since it is the most constant one and least likely to have any particles in it - and then get that rectangle's mean and use it as your image mean.

So, I did that with **ImageMagick** just in the Terminal. Here I am using a 5x5 grid rather than 10x10 to make the output smaller:

```
magick image.png -crop 5x5@ -format "%[standard-deviation] %[mean] %X %Y\n" info: | sort -n
```

**Output**

```
835.2 49706.8 +410 +613
835.915 50146.3 +614 +153
845.005 49458 +819 +613
850.8 49997.2 +410 +460
852.937 50198 +614 +306
854.049 49577.4 +205 +460
857.193 50051.1 +614 +460
858.613 49752.5 +614 +613
859.179 49557.4 +819 +460
870.186 49298.2 +819 +0
872.404 48692.2 +205 +0
877.883 49439.4 +205 +613
878.972 49458.6 +205 +306
880.427 49391.9 +410 +0
882.476 47767.1 +0 +0
887.067 49180.4 +205 +153
897.929 48872.3 +0 +613
921.144 49753.9 +819 +153
932.777 48344.7 +0 +153
956.651 48550.5 +0 +306
987.255 48661.6 +0 +460
988.145 49776.3 +819 +306
1005.76 49909 +410 +153
1009.17 49685.2 +614 +0
1272.57 50062.4 +410 +306
```

So, there are 25 lines - one line for each rectangle in the 5x5 grid. The first field on each line is the standard deviation in that rectangle, the second is the mean, the third is the x-offset of the top-left corner of the rectangle and the fourth is the y-offset of the top-left corner of the rectangle.

As I sorted by the standard deviation, the first line is the rectangle with the smallest variance, and its average grey value is 49706 on a scale of 0..65535. i.e. 193 on a scale of 0..255. That rectangle has its top-left corner at position [410,613]

---

You may be interested in *"Local Area Thresholding"*, see [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#lat). For example, on your image, you could highlight pixels that are 6% darker than their surrounding 100x100 area like this:

```
magick image.png -negate -lat 100x100+6%  result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I needed, this should work now no matter where the particles are located in my image. Thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.  Create a mask image by thresholding. Then get the mean of the pixels corresponding to the white pixels in the mask.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('gray_with_spots.png')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# count number of white pixels
mean = np.mean(img)
print("mean =",mean)

mean_masked = np.mean(img[np.where(thresh == 255)])
print("masked mean =",mean_masked)

# write thresh to disk
cv2.imwrite("gray_with_spots_thresh.png", thresh)

# display it
cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Mask:

[image]

Average Value:

mean = 191.81259179177545
masked mean = 192.3657402342317